# How can I add a raster (that is in a geodatabase) to map?

Tags: arcpy, raster

I know how to add a feature class to map in ArcGIS Pro using arcpy:

```
arcpy.MakeFeatureLayer_management(fc_output, 'fl_output')
layer = r'D:\ArcGIS_Pro_Projects\Optimity_Alf\Temp\fl.lyrx'
arcpy.SaveToLayerFile_management(fl, layer, 'ABSOLUTE')
lf = arcpy.mp.LayerFile(layer)
aprx = arcpy.mp.ArcGISProject('CURRENT')
map = aprx.listMaps('MyMap')[0]
refLyr = map.listLayers('Results')[0]
map.addLayerToGroup(refLyr,lf)
aprx.save()
```

But I wouldn't know how to do the same thing with a raster layer that is in a geodatabase. Any ideas?

Comment: Did you try MakeRasterLayer_management?

Comment: That creates a raster layer from a raster dataset (which I believe is what I have in my geodatabase. Not clear yet on the nomenclature). I might need that as an intermediate step to add raster to map, but I don't know.